# Interactive bearing measurement in Esri Production Mapping?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, esri-production-mapping

I have ArcGIS Desktop Advanced 10.4 and I want to use ARC Production Feature Builder to measure the bearing between two points just entered on the map, whilst there is a description of this function in the ESRI info, I believe it is only in the ARC Maritime extension. Am I mistaken with this assumption? if not how do I access it , it is not in the Customise>toolbars list. Otherwise is there a similar function available as an add in ?

Comment: Spatial analyst is ArcGis extension to facilitate raster analysis. Has nothing to do with your task

Comment: What kind of bearing are you after?  (e.g. Polar, Quadrant, etc?)

Answer (score 2):

Feature Builder is part of the [Production Mapping Extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/extensions/production-mapping).

A useful tool I have used for measuring bearings is the [COGO Report](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/creating-new-features/reporting-cogo-descriptions.htm) tool. It is included at the Standard license level and above, so you should have access to it. Find it on the COGO Toolbar. The tool is only active while you are in an edit session. One of its functions is described as such:

> Reports the direction and distance between two points you click on the map.